# Limit output from facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, for-loop

I got a script which gets facebook posts from a wall but I only want to display the latest 4 messages. The data is retrieved using file_get_contents, my problem is this also gets data that is useless and that I filtered out. For example if another person posts on the wall I don't want to show that post. This post is still retrieved (because it has the same name `message` as a message from the page owner) and thus counts as an array value.

I want to count the array and break if it's longer than 4. This doesn't work because of the latest 4 messages only 2 are messages posted by the page owner. Only if I turn the value to 8, it displays 4 messages but this is not future proof because if in the future the owner posts 8 messages in a row, then 8 messages will be displayed instead of 4.

My code:

```
$app_id = "23532523";
$app_secret = "secret";

//Retrieve auth token
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=23532523&client_secret=secret");

$size = 4;

$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/23532523/feed?fields=full_picture%2Cmessage%2Cstory%2Cpermalink_url%2Cupdated_time%2Cfrom&access_token=23532523");


$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

$f = 0;

foreach ( $feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data )
{
    if($feed_data->full_picture != ''){
        $fbimage = $feed_data->full_picture;
    }else{
        $fbimage = 'cms/images/placeholder/placeholder.jpg';
    }

    $shortstrfb = substr($feed_data->message, 0, 170) . '...';
    if(++$f > 8) break;

    if($feed_data->message != '' && $feed_data->from->name == 'page name'){
        $facebookfeed .= '
        <div class="col-sm-3 column_item_1">
            <div class="post_item post_item_news sc_blogger_item">
                <div class="post_featured">
                    <div class="post_thumb">
                        <div class="fbimgwrap">
                            <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$fbimage.'"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                                                    
                <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'"><h4 class="post_title sc_title sc_blogger_title">'.$feed_data->name.'</h4></a>           
                <div class="post_content sc_blogger_content">
                    <div class="post_descr" style="margin-top:-100px;height:200px;">
                        <p>'.$shortstrfb.'</p>
                        <div class="fbbutton">
                            <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank" class="sc_button sc_button_square sc_button_bg_underline sc_button_iconed ">
                                Bekijk op Facebook
                                <span class="sc_button_iconed icon-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>      
        </div>';
    }
}
echo $facebookfeed;
```

I now break the loop after 8 (should be 4, but with 8 it shows the last 4 at the moment).

Comment: If you don’t want posts by others, then consider using `/page-id/posts` instead, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/page/feed

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! Is there a way to filter stuff like 'user updated his profile picture' out of the file_get_contents? I thought that was the `story` parameter but if I remove it posts like that are still shown in the graph api explorer.

Comment: No, filtering the results in that regard is not possible. But you should not make API requests on every page load anyway (you run a risk of running into the API rate limits), but rather fetch new posts periodically, and cache the data on your end. (Webhooks would be another option to have Facebook notify your app when new posts are made on the page; but implementing those is a little more complex.)

Comment: Alright, i'll look into that. I fixed the problem by checking if a message exists, and only then add to `$f`.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it:

Only add to $f if $feed_data->message is not empty.

```
if($feed_data->message != ''){
    $f++;   
}

if($f > 4){
    break;  
}
```